# Is pub/sub a good choice for this scenario?

Tags: redis

I've just started messing arround with redis and the following scenario came to me:

Consider you have a submit form and you want to keep track of what people are writing in it (in a website). You also want to monitor it somewhere.

What I figure is, that since redis is single threaded, there will never be problems regarding who's turn it is to write on the block in redis's memory.

The question here, is weather the monitor should simply read from the same piece of information or if it should be subscribed to it and take the value from there ?

To a beginner like me it sounds that both approaches do essentially the same thing and both will require for the client to read from the field at a timed interval. Are there any significant differences?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design choice here is between PUSH or PULL. If the monitor reads data periodically from some source then it is PULLING data. But if it subscribes for the data then data is being PUSHED to it.

Difference between PUSH and PULL would be that in case of PULL monitor would always be periodically polling for more data. Whereas in case of PUSH (subscribe) data will be sent to monitor and hence it could sleep while there is no data to process.

PUB/SUB is a better design keeping above points in mind.

Monitor should have number of threads which should each subscribe to a channel where data would be published. Note once a thread subscribes to a channel it cannot issue any commands. It can only subscribe to more channels. In case monitor has to issue other commands then it should create a new connection.

Also we could look out for other ways of handling design problem in discussion.  As the amount of data to be processed could be huge and could cause huge work stacks for monitor. Message queues can be considered,where all data to be processed could be dumped. Monitor could act as consumer. Benefits with queues would be:

1. Messages could persist, in case monitor is down data would be stored in queues and processed when monitor is up.(Persistence)
2. Monitor could be scaled out to handle high loads.(Scalability)